# Comparing two files and applying the differences

Tags: linux, bash, shell, diff

on a Linux based system, I can easily compare two files, e.g.:

```
diff file1.txt file2.txt
```

...and see the difference between them.

What if I want to take all lines that are unique to `file2.txt` and apply them to file1.txt so that `file1.txt` will now contain everything it had + lines from `file2.txt` that it didn't have before? Is there an easy way to do it?

Comment: Have you tried the [**`patch`**](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/patch.1.html) command?

Comment: You need `diff -u`

Comment: @RonanBoiteau I found it shortly after I asked the question. Though I'm not sure how to apply changes to only one file.

Comment: Another alternative to look at is the `merge` command.

Comment: thank you all for suggestions. Please make them into answers so that you can get credit for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Using [**`patch`**](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/patch.1.html)

1. You can use [**`diff`**](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/diff.1.html)'s output to create a [**patch file**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patch_(Unix)).

   ```
   diff original_file file_with_new_lines > patch_file
   ```
2. You can edit `patch_file` to keep only the additions, since you only want the new lines.
3. Then you can use the [**`patch`**](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/patch.1.html) command to apply this patch file:

   ```
   patch original_file patch_file
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind appending the sorted diff to your file, you can use [comm](https://linux.die.net/man/1/comm):

```
cat file1.txt <(comm -13 <(sort f1.txt) <(sort f2.txt)) > file1.txt.patched
```

or

```
comm -13 <(sort f1.txt) <(sort f2.txt) | cat file1.txt - > file1.txt.patched
```

This will append the unique lines from file2.txt to file1.txt.

Comment: Not my downvote, but appending sorted lines to the end of the destination file is quite a lot more constrained than adding arbitrary lines where they are missing in a particular context.